# mysqli statement not working when url parameters present

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I have a news admin page which includes the following markup:

```
<ul>
  <?php newsArchive(); ?>
</ul>
```

The newsArchive function looks like this:

```
function newsArchive(){
    global $mysqli;
    $newsArchive = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT news_id,news_title,news_date FROM news ORDER by news_id DESC');
    $newsArchive->execute();
    $newsArchive->bind_result($archiveID,$archiveTitle,$archiveDate);
    while ($newsArchive->fetch()) {
      $archiveDate = date('M Y', strtotime($archiveDate));
      echo
      '<li class="clear">'.
        '<a class="left" href="news?edit-news='.$archiveID.'">'.$archiveTitle.'</a>'.
        '<span class="right">'.$archiveDate.'</span>'.
      '</li>';
    }
  }
```

Now this all works fine, except if I click on one of the links generated by the above PHP which takes me to the same page with URL parameters at the end. For example

```
mydomain.com/news?edit-news=1
```

Then I get the error: `Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on a non-object in`

Why is this happening? It's the same page running the same script. Works fine without URL parameters but those parameters shouldn't be interfering with the news archive.

Comment: That means the `prepare` statement doesn't return a valid `mysqli_stmt`. Use [`$mysql->error`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) to retrieve the last error message. BTW, always use `htmlspecialchars` when outputting data to HTML markup, otherwise your code is vulnerable to XSS.

Comment: So where's the function that's called when you click on a news article

Comment: If you use `if($newsArchive = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT news_id,news_title,news_date FROM news ORDER by news_id DESC'))` you will execute only if the query is right.

Comment: @MarkBaker the function is in a seperate php file that is included at the top of every page.

Comment: @ManoloSalsas Thanks but the query never changes so why does it work when there's no URL params and not when there is?

Comment: Correct, that query has no (obvious?) connection to any GET parameters – therefore: Are you absolutely sure you are looking at the _right_ query?

Comment: Why don't you retrieve the last error message with `$mysqli->error` (and not `$mysql->error`, as I erroneously said)?

Comment: Ah yes I can see the issue is with a different query now. One that deals with the GET parameter

Comment: Right, it's because I didn't close the connection after the first prepare statement on the page! Thanks for everyones help.

Comment: Maybe you should create an answer and accept it, just for people (like me) don't keep ending up here.

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like the issue was actually with other prepare statements on the page.

I wasn't closing the statements with for example:

```
$newsArchive->close();
```

That was therefore not allowing the next connect to work properly.